# How can I filter a json and get the mean to create a line plot in js?

Tags: javascript, json, filter, plotly, average

I have data in json format, so i want plot with plotly js, what i need is to create a plot of different states by semester, so i need to filter each state (example California), after that i need to get the mean of each semester and finally plot it.

So far i have this code, but i dont know how to filter im new in js

```
// Trace1 
var trace1 = {
  x: data.map(row => row.date),
  y: data.map(row => row.snap_biannual_chan),
  text: data.map(row => row.state_name),
  name: "snap_biannual_chan",
  type: "line"
};

// Combining both traces
var data = [trace1];

// Apply the group barmode to the layout
var layout = {
  title: "Practice",
  xaxis: {
    categoryorder: "array",
  }
};

// Render the plot to the div tag with id "plot"
Plotly.newPlot("plot", data, layout)
```

this is the json example:

"county_state_id": "06001",
    "pop_hispan_prop": ".1176472187212034",
    "pop_un_st": 3059000,
    "state_name": "California",
    "county_name": "Alameda County",
    "pop_un_co": 109000,
    "state_id": "06",
    "county_id": "001",
    "pop_co": 1605217,
    "pop_st": 38654206,
    "state_abbrev": "CA",
    "semester": "0118",
    "snap_beneficiaries": 102034,
    "snap_biannual_chan": -2.02980374083036,
    "sem": "Jan18",
    "pop_un_co_per": 6.790359185082141,
    "pop_un_st_per": 7.913757173022776,
    "year": 2018,
    "month": 1,
    "date": "January2018"

Comment: What is the question? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array `filter()` and `reduce()` methods to calculate the mean without having to micromanage a bunch of loops and variables. Here's an example:

```js
const data = [
  { state_id: "01", snap_biannual_chan: 5.5 },
  { state_id: "01", snap_biannual_chan: 3 },
  { state_id: "02", snap_biannual_chan: 5 }
];

const state01 = data.filter(x => x.state_id === "01");
const meanState01 = state01.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.sum += item.snap_biannual_chan;
  acc.mean = acc.sum / state01.length 
  return acc;
}, { sum: 0, mean: 0 });

console.log(meanState01);
console.log("the mean: ", meanState01.mean);
```